# Not pushing the values i need from JSON feed

Tags: json, google-apps-script

I am not getting the output from JSON parse.

```js
function pullJSON(data) {
 var url="https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/subcategories/?event_status=live&token=XXXXXXXXX&page_count=4"; // Paste your JSON URL here
  
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get feed
 var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); //
  
var keys = Object.keys(data).map(function(key){ 
  Logger.log(key + ':' + data[key]);
  return key + ':' + data[key]});
```

I only need subcategories: See JSON Below

```
{
"pagination": 
        {
        "object_count": 185, 
        "page_number": 1,             
        }, 

"subcategories": 
        {
        "resource_uri":https://www.eventbriteapi.com", 
        "id": "1001", 
        "name": "Startups & Small Business", 
        }
},
```

Comment: Please post response that you are getting from UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);